# Origin of the saying "you can't put a price on sanity"?

Tags: popular-refrains, phrase-origin

This is something my mother used to say on a daily basis, and I grew up thinking it was a common saying. Today it occurred to me that I've never heard anyone else say it, and when I googled it, no results came up.

Did my mother devise this on her own? Is this not an established saying? Was I completely fooled?

Comment: What is that even supposed to mean lmao

Answer (score 3):

It exists as the idiom "**you can't put a price on (something)**"- *origin unknown*. It means the "something" in question is "priceless" and has to be valued. I also see that your specific reference to "**sanity**" is used in a few obscure places online. So it is used, but it is not a very common expression.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/cant-put-a-price-on-somethingg

http://bravewords.com/news/metallica-drummer-lars-ulrich-talks-importance-of-family-life-all-four-of-us-prioritize-the-domestic-responsibilities-you-can-t-put-a-price-on-sanity